# How to exclude specific directories from "go to definition" in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> (or <kbd>F12</kbd>) to search and open the definitions in vscode. The problem is that my files are copied to another directory called `sketch` as I compile my code, so when I wanna open the definition of a function, VS shows both files (the real and the copied ones in the `sketch` folder), and sometimes I edit the copied file by mistake!

How can I exclude some folders from the "Go To definition"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem in a Javascript project.
None of the following solved it for me: files.exclude, files.watcherExclude, or search.exclude.

The solution was to add jsconfig.json to my project folder:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },

    "exclude": [
        "Backup",
        "Sketch"
    ]
}
```

This example specifies two folders to exclude: "Backup", and "Sketch".

If you are using TypeScript, use a tsconfig.json file instead.

Also see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig

Comment: I tried adding this to my project specific `settings.json` via **Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)** but it didn't work (C++ project)

Comment: FYI I do believe I got it working. I copied the config from here

https://github.com/SerenityOS/serenity/blob/a0356a0302571774b5c22f581454869f4283a5e6/Documentation/VSCodeConfiguration.md

Some subset of that did the trick, not sure which exactly

Answer (score 0):

Also struggle a lot because of the same problem

This should fix it:

```
# settings.json

"C_Cpp.files.exclude": {
    "**/sketch/**/*.hpp": true,
    "**/sketch/**/*.h": true
},

"C_Cpp.exclusionPolicy": "checkFilesAndFolders"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add files to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/sketch": true
},
```

Or files to exclude when searching (in files):

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/*.x": true,
},
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me for "Go to definition". cmd+clicking still showed ignored files.

Comment: No problem. Don't user the settings.json file, instead do this: Open VS User Settings (Main menu: `File` > `Preferences` > `Settings`). This will open the setting screen.
Search for `files:exclude` in the search at the top. Add your pattern.

Comment: Reload your window. This didn't seem to work for me until I did that.

Comment: @the21st please read the above comments. I forgot to tag ya.